# How can I get exactly the same amount elements replaced in numpy 2D matrix?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I got a symmetrical 2D numpy matrix, it only contains ones and zeros and diagonal elements are always 0.

I want to replace part of the elements from one to zero, and the result need to keep symmetrical too. How many elements will be selected depends on the parameter`replace_rate`.

Since it's a symmetrical  matrix, I take half of the matrix and select the elements(those values are 1) randomly, change them from 1 to 0. And then with a mirror operation, make sure the whole matrix are still symmetrical.

For example

```
com = np.array ([[0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                 [1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
                 [1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
                 [1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
                 [1, 1, 1, 1, 0]])

replace_rate = 0.1
com = np.triu(com)
mask = np.random.choice([0,1],size=(com.shape),p=((1-replace_rate),replace_rate)).astype(np.bool)
r1 = np.random.rand(*com.shape) 
com[mask] = r1[mask] 
com += com.T - np.diag(com.diagonal())
```

com is a (5,5) symmetrical matrix, and 10% of elements (only include those values are 1, the diagonal elements are excluded) will be replaced to 0 randomly.

The question is , how can I make sure the amount of elements changed keep the same each time?
Keep the same `replace_rate = 0.1`, sometimes I will get result like:

```
com = np.array([[0 1 1 1 1]
                [1 0 1 1 1]
                [1 1 0 1 1]
                [1 1 1 0 1]
                [1 1 1 1 0]])
```

Actually no one changed this time, and if I repeat it, I got 2 elements changed :

```
com = np.array([[0 1 1 1 1]
                [1 0 1 1 1]
                [1 1 0 1 0]
                [1 1 1 0 1]
                [1 1 0 1 0]])
```

I want to know how to fix the amount of elements changed with the same `replace_rate`?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You are already always making the same number of replacements, it's just that sometimes your replacement value happens to be the same as the original value, so the array is identical.

Rather, you could randomly select which *elements* to change, and set their value to the opposite of the original value (so 0->1, 1->0)

Comment: Thanks a lot! But how about if I  only want to select from the off -diagonal elements? the replace_rate should only have effect on these elements which original value is 1. How should I change my code? Thanks !@SimonR

Comment: If I set the initial matrix like: ```com = np.array ([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])```  replace_rate = 0.2, Sine it's a 5*5 matrix, it should always be 5 elements changed. But I can still got result like ```[[1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 0 1 1]
 [1 0 1 1 0]
 [1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 0 1 1]]``  4 got changed, and result like : ```[[1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 0 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 0 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1]]``` only 2 got changed.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
def make_transform(m, replace_rate):

    changed = []  # keep track of indices we already changed

    def get_random():
        # Get a random pair of indices which are not equal (i.e. not on the diagonal)
        c1, c2 = random.choices(range(len(com)), k=2)
        if c1 == c2 or (c1,c2) in changed or (c2,c1) in changed:
            return get_random() # Recurse until we find an i,j pair : i!=j , that hasnt already been changed
        else:
            changed.append((c1,c2))
            return c1, c2

    n_changes = int(m.shape[0]**2 * replace_rate) # the number of changes to make
    print(n_changes)
    for _ in range(n_changes):
        i, j = get_random()  # Get an valid index 
        m[i][j] = m[j][i] = 0  

    return m
```

Comment: Thanks again! I will check this now, I think it will work！@SimonR

Comment: Thank you @SimonR :)). Although the amount still fluctuates a bit , it's a good idea. Thanks anyway!

Comment: It's because you can't change an odd number of elements and still keep a symmetrical matrix. So when you try to change 5 elements, it'll actually change either 2 or 3. Also sometimes you will end up changing an element, and then changing it back. I changed my answer to keep track of which elements have already been changed. It should work as you intended now.

Comment: Is alignment missing  about the first row and the last row? Or they should be deleted?

Comment: You're correct : I missed an indentation. Fixed it now.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I will rethink about my option, maybe I should change my goal a bit, as you say, sometimes it seems inevitable to have different results

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I suggest:

```
def rand_zero(mat, replace_rate):
    triu_mat = np.triu(mat)

    _ind = np.where(triu_mat != 0)              # gets indices of non-zero elements, not just non-diagonals
    ind = [x for x in zip(*_ind)]

    chng = np.random.choice(range(len(ind)),    # select some indices, at rate 'replace_rate'
           size = int(replace_rate*mat.size), 
           replace = False)                     # do not select duplicates

    mod_mat = triu_mat
    for c in chng:
        mod_mat[ind[c]] = 0
    mod_mat = mod_mat + mod_mat.T

    return mod_mat
```

I use `int()` to truncate to an integer in `size`, but you can use `round()` if that's what you desire.

Hope this gives consistent results!

Comment: Thanks a lot, with ```int``` or ```round```, it's possible to have consistent results:))